# sampled FT of Continuous time LTI output

Tags: sampling, fourier, transform

I am trying to compute the sampled Fourier Transform of a Continuous Time LTI system output. $x(t)$ is the input of LTI and $h(t)$ is the impulse res. $y(t)$ is the output. we know that

$$ y(t) = \int_0^\infty x(t_1)h(t-t_1) dt_1 $$

after sampling,
$$  y(nT_s) = \int_0^\infty x(t_1)h(nT_s-t_1) dt_1  $$

$$ Y(j\omega)=\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}y(nT_s)e^{-j\omega nT_s}  $$

i don't know how to perform the computation next to get sampled F.T related with $ X(j\omega),H(j\omega)$ since i don't know to to deal with $t_1$.
i know there is another way to cal. the sampled LTI. output F.T. for example, just consider the C.T  LTI output as a total, and its sampled F.T is easy to achieve, and the replace it by
$ X(j\omega)H(j\omega)$.
so, please help if you know how.

Comment: Are you assuming that you have no aliasing, i.e. that $x(t)$ and $h(t)$ are both bandlimited with a bandwidth of less than $\frac{1}{2T_s}$ ?

Comment: i guess, that's doesn't matter. it is general case.

Comment: The relationships between discrete and continuous Fourier transforms are very different between the  Aliasing and the non-aliasing case.

Comment: @Hilmar, thanks. if just look at the C.T LTI output y(t), and its F.T is Yc(jω), and do the sampling, we know the dis. time F.T. by replacing Yc(jω) with XH, we get the answer. but, how do we derive it from the convolution as I listed

Comment: No we don't get the answer. Certainly not when there is aliasing and it really depends how you choose the parameters for the different Fourier Transform types (there are 4 different types).

Comment: hi Hilmar, here is my understanding: if y(t) is directly sampled, and we know the dis. F.T is $$Y_d(j\omega)=1/T_s\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}Y(j(\omega + n\omega_s))$$, then we replace $Y(j\omega)$ by $H(j\omega)X(j\omega)$

Answer (score 1):

##### Convolution theorem derivation

The convolution theorem states that the Fourier Transform of the convolution of two signals is the product of their respective Fourier transforms:

$$y(t) = (x * h)(t) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{FT}} Y(\omega) = X(\omega)H(\omega)$$
Let's go through the proof:

$$ Y(\omega)=\int^\infty_{-\infty}y(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt = \int^\infty_{-\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t_1)h(t-t_1)dt_1\right)e^{-j\omega t}dt $$
Re-arranging, and dropping the integral indexes:
$$ = \int x(t_1) \left[\int h(t-t_1)e^{-j\omega t}dt\right]dt_1 = \int x(t_1) \bigg[\mathcal{FT}\{h(t-t_1)\}\bigg]dt_1 $$ where I put brackets for you to see where we use the F.T definition.

Now by the shift property of the Fourier transform, $\mathcal{FT}\{h(t-t_1)\} = e^{-j\omega t_1}H(\omega)$ so continuing,
$$ = \int x(t_1)e^{-j\omega t_1}H(\omega)dt_1 = \left[\int x(t_1)e^{-j\omega t_1}dt_1\right]H(\omega) = X(\omega)H(\omega)$$
To summarize:
$$Y(\omega) = X(\omega)H(\omega)$$

##### Sampling operation in the Frequency Domain

The sampling operation with frequency $f_s = \dfrac{1}{T_s}$ can be defined as:
$$y_s(t) = y(nT_s) = y(t)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-nT_s) = y(t) \frac{1}{T_s}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{jk\omega_st} = \frac{1}{T_s}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}y(t)e^{jk\omega_st}$$
where:

- $\omega_s = 2\pi/T_s$
- $\delta(t-nT_s)$ is an *impulse train* with period $T_s$ (i.e *sampling frequency* $\tfrac{1}{T_s}$), and since it's periodic with period $T_s$, we can use its Fourier series $\frac{1}{T_s}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{jk\omega_st}$

In the frequency domain, taking the Fourier transform of $x_s(t)$ (I'll leave you to prove this yourself using the shifting property), we get:
$$Y_s(\omega) = \frac{1}{T_s}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}Y(\omega - k\omega_s)$$

##### Bringing the two together:

$$Y_s(\omega) = \frac{1}{T_s}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}X(\omega - k\omega_s)H(\omega - k\omega_s)$$
The discrete version is exactly the same, except $\omega \rightarrow \Omega$ with $\Omega = \omega T_s$:
$$Y_s(\Omega) = \frac{1}{T_s}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}X(\Omega - k2\pi)H(\Omega - k2\pi)$$

Comment: thanks for the correction!

Comment: No problem! If the link provided doesn't answer your question, let me know, and I'll be happy to edit my answer by writing it out with your notation.
Basically you just need to replace  $y(nT_s)$ in $Y(j\omega)$ by the convolution expression, then go through the convolution theorem proof ;)

Comment: actually it doesn't answer my question. maybe I didn't explain it very well. my question is, how to derive the discrete F.T of sampled LTI output related to input $X(j\omega)$ and impulse res. $H(j\omega)$

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what you're asking... I'll edit my answer, hopefully you'll understand what you're asking and how that relates to the convolution theorem.

Comment: thanks again. but if you look at your result, do you see any spectra repeat? remember it is discrete F.T. not continuous time F.T

Comment: Ok, your question was a little un-clear then... Still, I tried one last thing for you, hopefully that will answer it! otherwise I'm giving up!